# IdentityServer3 - is it possible to specify custom parameter for identity token?

Tags: c#, thinktecture-ident-server, identityserver3

Is it possible to specify another GET/POST parameter name instead of id_token (like blabla_token) when returning an identity token back to Web Application, and make this parameter name customizable inside C# code of custom services registered in IdentityServerServiceFactory.

The callback url should look like http://someserver.com/auth/?blabla_token=tokencontent

Comment: I don't really follow - but the answer is probably - no.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Some application that use the identity server need their custom token name, and it is not possible to change that.